# Early detection of machine (laptop, desktop, server, etc...) failure

Tags: security, data-loss-prevention

Is there some kind of software application or hardware devices that can inform the owner of the machine that some kind of failure is going to happen soon?

What I mean by some kind of failure are - hard disk failure, ram failure, monitor failure, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer from Journeyman Geek and Bryan, I can conclude that there is currently no software suite (at this point of time) that can perform early detection of a machine (be it a laptop, server, desktop) failures.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often failure is at a lower level than tools can detect. There's specific troubleshooting tools for specific issues though

Hard Drives: I tend to use [gsmartcontrol](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home) to check drive health. Works on most common OSes

Ram: i tend to favour [memtestx86+](http://www.memtest.org/) run off a liveusb. I usually run this sparingly though, or when suspecting ram issues

BSODs: Quite often BSODs can be an indication of other issues - i use [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) to interpret these

there's no standard test for other things as far as i know

Comment: Yes, those program require to be run manually and each of them can only detect a specify kind of hardware failure. I am looking of a early-detection program that probably perform checkup on the machine when the machine is not doing work and popup a information message informing the owner which hardware (can be harddisk, monitor display, etc..) may fail in the next few days.

Comment: My objective is to detect the failure before it fail and to replace that particular part(s) that may/will fail (probably in the next few days).

Answer (score 0):

[Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) can tell you about the state of your hard drive.

Comment: Can it also detect other machine failures?

Comment: no, it's a hard drive tool.